# displaying ground overlay completely inside polygon boundaries in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, overlay, polygon

I am trying to display Ground Overlay completely inside polygon boundaries. I tried increasing latitude and longitude by some meters, but the result is not as I expected please help me.

This is my image:

[image]

```
                        double meters = widthtemp2;
                    double coef = meters * 0.0000089;
                    double new_lat = newlatlngs.latitude + coef;
                    double new_long = newlatlngs.longitude + coef / Math.cos(newlatlngs.latitude * 0.018);

                  LatLng finallatlng = new LatLng(new_lat, new_long);
                    mGroundOverlay = mMap.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                            .image(mImages.get(mCurrentEntry))
                            .position(finallatlng, (float) (0.985*widthpanel), (float) (1.646*heightpanel)));
```

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @user2314737 yes i included the code please check it out